# Запуск скриптов вместе с django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

С django работаю не так давно. Возник вопрос: можно ли с запуском django запускать другие скрипты, находящиеся в приложениях? К примеру:

Структура проекта:

```
--MyProject
   --SettingsFolder
   --MyApp1
      --Script1
      --Script2
   --MyApp2
```

Необходимо, чтобы Script1 и Script2 запускались, желательно одновременно, при запуске django.

---

Примечание: использовал импорт настроек в Script1

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dmb.settings')
django.setup()
```

Но при добавление его в Script2, Script2 не выполнялся.

Comment: Зачем вам их запускать? Что они делают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from MyApp1 import Script1, Script2

settings.configure(default_settings='MyApp1.apps.MyApp1Config', DEBUG=True)
django.setup()
```